# Is it advisable to remove X and Y chromosome genes in a bulk RNA-seq dataset at the level of the count matrix?

Tags: rna-seq, deseq2

From this link [remove X and Y chromosome genes in RNA-seq data using DESeq2 pipeline](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/67237/), I have learned that depending on context, it is perfectly valid to remove X and Y chromosomal genes in an RNA-seq dataset before doing differential expression analysis. However I only have access to the count matrix and not the **bam** files of the RNA seq data I am analysing. Is it advisable to do the X and Y chromosome gene removal at the level of the count matrix? I am talking about removing all rows that contain X and Y chromosomal genes from the **.csv** count matrix file read in to **RStudio** before proceeding to create the **DESeq2** object.

Thank you in advance for your kind response.

Comment: First off, it can be valid, but why do you want to do so? In my lab we use them as a validation (does sample X that is a male, has gene expression of Y?). I think that removing them leads to more work with unclear benefit: what if there is a relevant gene in the X chromosome?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It is almost never a good idea and will most likely not have the effect that you think it will (e.g., it won't remove gender differences).

Comment: @Devon Ryan :  Thank you very much for your response. Do you please have a supporting publication?

Comment: No one would ever bother writing a paper about something that is (A) almost never done and (B) rarely useful.